# Angular - Sharing the data between components, getting null data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I'm trying to share the data received from a service in one component to another component but getting null data.

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AService {

  private data = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public data$ = this.data.asObservable();

  getData(){
    // http get service
  }

  setData(newData) { 
    this.data.next(newData);
  }
}
```

Component 1:

```
@Component({
  selector: "component1",
  templateUrl: "../html/component1.html",
  styleUrls: ["../css/component1.css"],
  providers: [AService]
})
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

    constructor(private aService: AService) {}

    getData(corpId: string, type: string) {
    this.aService
      .getData
      .subscribe(newData => {
        this.aService.setData(newData);
        // some other code.
      });
  }
}
```

Component 2:

```
@Component({
  selector: "component2",
  templateUrl: "../html/component2.html",
  styleUrls: ["../css/component2.css"],
  providers: [AService]
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

    newData: any;

    constructor(private aService: AService) {
        this.aService.data$.subscribe(data => this.newData = data);  // data is null as this statement is getting called first before the component 1
    }

}
```

Component 2 constructor is getting called before the Component 1 `getData()` method. Both components are in the same page, I want the component1 to load first and then component in order to get the data from component1 in to component2.

IN another base component I have used the both selectors as below:

```
<component1></component1>

<component2></component2>
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile. Post code that compiles, and reproduces the problem you're facing. Don't put comments instead of the critical code related to your question. While you're at it, post it as a stackblitz, so that we can see the problem in action.

Comment: Conceptually your components should work as described. But without a working stackblitz as requested above, it would be difficult to see what may be causing the issue.

Comment: Your code will work after doing two simple modifications 1. in Service private data change to public  2. in component 2 this.aService.data$ change to this.aService.data

Answer (score 0):

What I should advice you is to combine a ngIf (in the html parent) and another variable in your service. Like this when component 1 is done, it updates the variable and the component 2 will be load.

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
@Injectable()
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})

/**
 * Service to manage all the global variables in order to use it in different components
 */
export class AService {

  private data = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public data$ = this.data.asObservable();

  // Global variable to know if component 1 is done
  private isComponent1Source = new BehaviorSubject(false); // Set up the source
  isComponent1 = this.isComponent1Source.asObservable(); // Make it Observable

  constructor() {}

  /**
   * Function to change the variable from a component
   * @param done boolean to display the info experiment
   */
  setIsComponent1(done: any) {
    this.isComponent1Source.next(done);
  }

  getData(){
  // http get service
  }

  setData(newData) { 
   this.data.next(newData);
  }

}
```

**Component 1:**

```
@Component({
  selector: "component1",
  templateUrl: "../html/component1.html",
  styleUrls: ["../css/component1.css"],
  providers: [AService]
})
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

    constructor(private aService: AService) {}

    getData(corpId: string, type: string) {
    this.aService
      .getData
      .subscribe(newData => {
        this.aService.setData(newData);
        this.aService.setIsComponent1(true);
        // some other code.
      });
  }
}
```

**Component 2**

```
@Component({
  selector: "component2",
  templateUrl: "../html/component2.html",
  styleUrls: ["../css/component2.css"],
  providers: [AService]
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

    newData: any;

    constructor(private aService: AService) {
        this.aService.data$.subscribe(data => this.newData = data);
    }

}
```

**Parent Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: "componentParent",
  templateUrl: "../html/componentparent.html",
  styleUrls: ["../css/componentParent.css"],
  providers: [AService]
})
export class ComponentParent implements OnInit {

    done = false;

    constructor(private aService: AService) {
        this.aService.isComponent1.subscribe(res => this.done = res);
    }

}
```

**Parent HTML:**

```
<component1></component1>
<component2 *ngIf="done"></component2>
```